# обращение к макету по разным id

Tags: android, android-fragment

Всем привет. Начал изучать фрагменты и появился вопрос:

Почему макет контейнерного представления использует разные обращения по id в методах

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

Comment: потому что ID xml-разметки для активити, на которой расположен фрагмент и ID самого фрагмента это разные вещи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому, что в первом случае к фрагменту подключается макет его визуального отображения (вёрстка), а во втором случае идёт инициализация фрагмента размещённого внутри другого фрагмента или `Activity`.

Если фрагмент помещается в макет другого фрагмента или `Activity` и с ним нужно как-то работать в коде, ему присваивается специальный `id`. Также как и любому другому виджету (кнопке, списку и т.д.).